# How to extract useful info from cProfile with Pandas and Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, profiling

I have some Python code that is generating a large data set via numerical simulation. The code is using Numpy for a lot of the calculations and Pandas for a lot of the top-level data. The data sets are large so the code is running slowly, and now I'm trying to see if I can use cProfile to find and fix some hot spots.

The trouble is that cProfile is identifying a lot of the hot spots as pieces of code within Pandas, within Numpy, and/or Python builtins. Here are the cProfile statistics sorted by 'tottime' (total time within the function itself). Note that I'm obscuring project name and file names since the code itself is not owned by me and I don't have permission to share details.

```
foo.sort_stats('tottime').print_stats(50)
Wed Jun  5 13:18:28 2019    c:\localwork\xxxxxx\profile_data

         297514385 function calls (291105230 primitive calls) in 306.898 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 4141 to 50 due to restriction <50>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   281307   31.918    0.000   34.731    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.infer_dtype}
      800   31.443    0.039   31.476    0.039 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:4703(delete)
   109668   23.837    0.000   23.837    0.000 {method 'clear' of 'dict' objects}
   153481   19.369    0.000   19.369    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  5861614   14.182    0.000   78.492    0.000 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3090(get_value)
  5861614    8.891    0.000    8.891    0.000 {method 'get_value' of 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine' objects}
  5861614    8.376    0.000   99.084    0.000 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:764(__getitem__)
 26840695    7.032    0.000   11.009    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
 26489324    6.547    0.000   14.410    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
 11846279    6.177    0.000   19.809    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.values_from_object}
[...]
```

Is there a sensible way for me to figure out which parts of my code are excessively leaning on these library functions and built-ins? I anticipate one answer would be "look at the cumulative time statistics, that will probably indicate where these costly calls are originating". The cumulative times give a little bit of insight:

```
foo.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats(50)
Wed Jun  5 13:18:28 2019    c:\localwork\xxxxxx\profile_data

         297514385 function calls (291105230 primitive calls) in 306.898 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 4141 to 50 due to restriction <50>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    643/1    0.007    0.000  307.043  307.043 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000  307.043  307.043 xxxxxx.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002  306.014  306.014 xxxxxx.py:264(write_xxx_data)
        1    0.187    0.187  305.991  305.991 xxxxxx.py:256(write_yyyy_data)
        1    0.077    0.077  305.797  305.797 xxxxxx.py:250(make_zzzzzzz)
        1    0.108    0.108  187.845  187.845 xxxxxx.py:224(generate_xyzxyz)
   108223    1.977    0.000  142.816    0.001 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:298(_setitem_with_indexer)
        1    0.799    0.799  126.733  126.733 xxxxxx.py:63(populate_abcabc_data)
        1    0.030    0.030  117.874  117.874 xxxxxx.py:253(<listcomp>)
     7201    0.077    0.000  116.612    0.016 C:\LocalWork\xxxxxx\yyyyyyyyyyyy.py:234(xxx_yyyyyy)
   108021    0.497    0.000  112.908    0.001 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:182(__setitem__)
  5861614    8.376    0.000   99.084    0.000 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:764(__getitem__)
   110024    0.917    0.000   81.210    0.001 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py:3500(apply)
   108021    0.185    0.000   80.685    0.001 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py:3692(setitem)
  5861614   14.182    0.000   78.492    0.000 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3090(get_value)
   108021    1.887    0.000   73.064    0.001 C:\LocalWork\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py:819(setitem)
[...]
```

Is there a good way to pin down the hot spots -- better than "crawl through xxxxxx.py and search for all places where Pandas might be inferring a dataype, and where Numpy might be deleting objects"...?

Comment: Partial answer to my own question, or at least some introductory info. In my code I was iterating through the DataFrame (using `iterrows()`) in many places because I thought there was no good way to do it otherwise. Then I found the excellent tutorial [A Beginner’s Guide to Optimizing Pandas Code for Speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), which taught me that 1) if you must iterate, there are better ways to do it, and 2) avoiding iteration (i.e. vectorizing the operations) might be easier than you think.

Comment: To find where these functions are being called, you can use the `callers` property in `cProfile` or `pstats`